# Supporting OAuth in Kafka on a production environment

Tags: java, apache-kafka, oauth

I have a java application which can be deployed in a cluster mode itself. I want to implement OAuth and regarding the [Kafka official documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/7.6/kafka/authentication_sasl/authentication_sasl_oauth.html#overview) I can't use classes provided by the kafka clients library and for production use I have to implement:

- LoginCallbackHandler in Kafka client (implementing the Authenticate handler)
- ValidatorCallbackHandler in Kafka broker (implementing the Authenticate handler)

I was taking a look how it looks in the [strimzi-kafka-oauth](https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-oauth) library and these handlers are pretty clear but I have couple of questions:

1. If the validator callback handler detects that a token is no longer valid, it either throws an exception or directly return an error through callback.error(). Then it looks that it indicates kafka to call the login call back handler again to login with a refresh token. How is this broker-> client communication performed when validator callback handler is on the broker side and login callback handler is on the client side? Or is the login callback handler directly called from the broker?
2. If the statement above is correct, is calling the login callback handler implemented in kafka in a thread safe manner? I'm worried about concurrent refresh token calls..
3. Per the documentation if the broker acts as a [interbroker listener](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/7.6/kafka/authentication_sasl/authentication_sasl_oauth.html#configure-ak-brokers) the user has to define the login callback handler also in the broker's config. How does this work then? Should be the login callback handler part of the Kafka broker or it can still stay within the client and it's just needed to reference it?

I would appreciate some help from someone who has more knowledge, as the official Kafka documentation is not very robust.. Thanks!